# Make a view appear and disappear in a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I want to make a view appear out of a button (slide up and zoom) on click and then on tap again disappear in same fashion into that button. I have achieved a view coming out of a button with this code. But reverse is not working. any help

```
- (IBAction) arrowBtnClick{

    _arrowUpBtn.enabled=false;
    if (_isSliderMenuPresent) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            _sliderView.frame = CGRectMake(_sliderView.frame.origin.x, 440.0f, _sliderView.frame.size.width, 200 );
        } completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             _isSliderMenuPresent = false;
             _sliderView.hidden = true;
             _arrowUpBtn.enabled=true;
             [_arrowUpBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         }];
    }
    else{
        _sliderView.hidden = false;
        _sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.00, 0.00);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            _sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            _sliderView.frame = CGRectMake(_sliderView.frame.origin.x,_sliderView.frame.origin.y-150, _sliderView.frame.size.width, 200 );
        } completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             _isSliderMenuPresent = true;
             _arrowUpBtn.enabled=true;
             [_arrowUpBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         }];
    }   
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Does it do nothing? Does it disappear immediately? Does it animate to the wrong place?

Comment: On first button tap slider view comes out of arrowbutton correctly(animated scale up). But when i press button again it just go back move down not fade into arrow button.

Comment: Put in some breakpoints and step through the code. It sounds like maybe your `_isSliderMenuPresent` BOOL is getting set to `true` again somewhere else.

Comment: Not an answer persay but [check this out](https://github.com/Ciechan/BCGenieEffect). It's really nice.